# UPDADE de informações do BD

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados, formulário

Olá Meu projeto tem um form que trás as informações do BD caso o usuário queira editar, ele não está alterando os dados, nem a imagem..

form:

```
  <?php 
  $id = $_GET["id"];
  //Executar consulta
  $result = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1");
 $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 ?>

<div class="container" style="width: 100%">

<div class="page-header"><h1>Editar de Vídeo</h1></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="processa/proc_edit_vid.php"  >

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Título</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="texto" class="form-control" name="nome" placeholder="Título do Vídeo" value="<?php echo $resultado['nome'] ?>">
        </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Descrição</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="desc_vid" placeholder="Descrição do Vídeo"><?php echo $resultado['desc_vid'] ?></textarea>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tempo</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="texto" class="form-control" name="tempo" placeholder="Tempo de Vídeo" value="<?php echo $resultado['tempo'] ?>">
        </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Star 1</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="texto" class="form-control" name="star_1" placeholder="PornStar 1" value="<?php echo $resultado['star_1'] ?>">
        </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Star 2</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="texto" class="form-control" name="star_2" placeholder="PornStar 2" value="<?php echo $resultado['star_2'] ?>">
        </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Imagem </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="file" name="imagem"></div>
</div>
<?php   
$foto = $resultado['imagem'];
    if($foto == ""){?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Imagem  BD</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                O Vídeo não possui Imagem
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
}
    if($foto != ""){?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Imagem do BD</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <img src="<?php echo "video/thumb/$foto"; ?>" width="100" height="100">
                <input type="hidden" name="img_antiga" value='<?php echo $foto ?>'>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php } ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tags</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="texto" class="form-control" name="tags" placeholder="Tags" value="<?php echo $resultado['tags'] ?>">
        </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="description" placeholder="Descrição que o Google Recebe"><?php echo $resultado['description'] ?></textarea>
        </div>
</div>

<?php $categoria_id = $resultado['categoria_id']; ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Categoria</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control" name="categoria_id">
                <option>Selecione</option>
                <?php 
                    $result_cat = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT * FROM categorias");
                while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_cat)){
                    $id_categoria = $dados['id'];
                ?>  
                <option value="<?php echo $dados["id"];?>"<?php if($id_categoria == $categoria_id){echo 'Selected';} ?>
                ><?php echo $dados["nome"];?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
</div>


<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $resultado['id']; ?>">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Editar</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div><br>
</div></div>
```

Como Foram salvos

```
    $nome = $conectar->real_escape_string($nome);
    $desc_vid = $conectar->real_escape_string($desc_vid);
    $tempo = $conectar->real_escape_string($tempo);
    $star_1 = $conectar->real_escape_string($star_1);
    $star_2 = $conectar->real_escape_string($star_2);
    $nome_final = $conectar->real_escape_string($nome_final);
    $categoria_id = $conectar->real_escape_string($categoria_id);
    $tags = $conectar->real_escape_string($tags);
    $description = $conectar->real_escape_string($description);

    $query = mysqli_query($conectar, "INSERT INTO videos (nome, desc_vid, tempo, star_1, star_2, imagem, categoria_id, tags, description, created) VALUES ('".$nome."', '".$desc_vid."', '".$tempo."', '".$star_1."', '".$star_2."', '".$nome_final."', '".$categoria_id."', '".$tags."', '".$description."', NOW())") or die(mysqli_error($conectar));
```

PHP de Edição

```
    <?php   session_start();
    include_once("../seguranca.php");
    include_once("../conexao.php");

    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $nome = $_POST["nome"];
    $desc_vid = $_POST["desc_vid"];
    $tempo = $_POST["tempo"];
    $star_1 = $_POST["star_1"];
    $star_2 = $_POST["star_2"];
    $imagem = $_FILES['imagem']['name'];
    $categoria_id = $_POST["categoria_id"];
    $tags = $_POST["tags"];
    $description = $_POST["description"];
    $img_antiga = $_POST["img_antiga"];

    if($imagem == ""){
    $nome = $conectar->real_escape_string($nome);
    $desc_vid = $conectar->real_escape_string($desc_vid);
    $tempo = $conectar->real_escape_string($tempo);
    $star_1 = $conectar->real_escape_string($star_1);
    $star_2 = $conectar->real_escape_string($star_2);
    $nome_final = $conectar->real_escape_string($nome_final);
    $categoria_id = $conectar->real_escape_string($categoria_id);
    $tags = $conectar->real_escape_string($tags);
    $description = $conectar->real_escape_string($description);
    $img_antiga = $conectar->real_escape_string($img_antiga);

    $query = mysqli_query($conectar, "UPDADE videos set nome='$nome', desc_vid='$desc_vid', tempo='$tempo', star_1='$star_1', star_2='$star_2', categoria_id='$categoria_id', tags='$tags', description='$description', modified = NOW() WHERE id='$id'");
        if (mysqli_affected_rows($conectar) != 0){
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
          alert(\"Editado com Sucesso.\");
    </script>
    ";
    }else {
        echo "
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
            alert(\"Edição não Realizado.\");
        </script>
        ";
    }
    } /* Comentado até o fim, pra testar o UPDADE
    else{
    // Local onde imagem vai ser salva
    $_UP['pasta'] = 'video/thumb/';
    // Tamanho da imagem
    $_UP['tamanho'] = 1024*1024*100; //5Mb
    // Exrensões permitidas
    $_UP['extensoes'] = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif');
    // Renomear a imagem
    $_UP['renomear'] = false;

    // Tipos de erro de UpLoad do PHP
    $_UP['erros'][0] = 'Não houve erro';
    $_UP['erros'][1] = 'Imagem maior que o limite do php';
    $_UP['erros'][2] = 'Imagem muito grande';
    $_UP['erros'][3] = 'UpLoad da imagem feita parcialmente';
    $_UP['erros'][4] = 'Erro no UpLoad da imagem';

    // Verifica se houve algum erro
    if($_FILES['imagem']['erros'] != 0){
        die("Não foi possivel fazer UpLoad, Erro: <br />". $_UP['erros']        [$_FILES['imagem']['erros']]);
        exit;
    }

    // Verifica qual a extensão
    $img_nome = $_FILES['imagem']['name'];
    $img_separador = explode('.', $img_nome);
    $extensao = strtolower(end($img_separador));
    //$extensao = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['imagem']['name'])));
    if(array_search($extensao, $_UP['extensoes'])=== false){
echo "
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    alert(\"Arquivo não compatível: png, jpg, jpeg e gif. \");
</script>
";
    }
    // Verifica o tamanho
    else if ($_UP['tamanho'] < $_FILES['imagem']['size']){
echo "Imagem muito grande, limite de 5Mb";
    }
    // Salva nos arquivos do site
    else{
//Verifica se deve trocar o nome da imagem
if($_UP['renomear'] == true){
    // Cria nome Baseado no UNIX TIMESTAMP atual e com extensão
    $nome_final = time().'.jpg';
}else{
    // Mantem o nome da imagem
    $nome_final = $_FILES['imagem']['name'];
}
// Verifica se é possivel mover a imagem para a pasta escolhida
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'], $_UP['pasta'].$nome_final)){
    // Upload efetuado com sucesso

    echo "
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    alert(\"Editado com Sucesso.\");
</script>
";
}else{
    // Falha no UpLoad

    echo "
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    alert(\"Edição não Realizado.\");
</script>
";
    }
}
    }*/
?>
```

Comment: Nos dois últimos `UPDATE` você tá colocando pontos tentando concatenar, mas não está fechando as aspas duplas antes e reabrindo-as depois das variáveis.

Comment: esse é o problema, estou tentando editar um produto que já tem imagem, então como if($imagem == "") ele só executa o primeiro UPDATE, (já comentei o código apos o else) ele apresenta o alerta que foi editado(adicionei o mesmo alerta do else), porém não alterou nenhum campo no BD

Answer (score 1):

Os updates conforme KillerJack destacou envolvendo variáveis com aspas duplas.

```
"UPDADE videos SET nome='".$nome."', desc_vid='".$desc_vid."', -----
```

Mas também pode-se omiti-las retirando os pontos de concatenação.

`"UPDADE videos SET nome='$nome', desc_vid='$desc_vid', -----`

```
$query = mysqli_query($conectar, "UPDADE videos SET nome='$nome', desc_vid='$desc_vid', tempo='$tempo', star_1='$star_1', star_2='$star_2', imagem='$nome_final', categoria_id='$categoria_id', tags='$tags', description='$description', modified = NOW() WHERE id='$id'");


$query = mysqli_query($conectar, "UPDADE videos SET nome='$nome', desc_vid='$desc_vid', tempo='$tempo', star_1='$star_1', star_2='$star_2', categoria_id='$categoria_id', tags='$tags', description='$description', modified = NOW() WHERE id='$id'");
```

Comment: esse é o problema, estou tentando editar um produto que já tem imagem, então como if($imagem == "") ele só executa o primeiro UPDATE, (já comentei o código apos o else) ele apresenta o alerta que foi editado(adicionei o mesmo alerta do else), porém não alterou nenhum campo no BD.